# Laravel - Class filter.parser does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

**I have resigned myself to upgrading to Laravel 4.1.x (the `composer.json` kind of installed that for me, so I updated my controller alias as mentioned by Antonio Carlos Ribeiro), but have a different problem now:**

*EDIT*: I ended up doing a fresh install (after copying what little public files I had over) as on Adam Rivers post after cloning a fresh Laravel repo, and it works now.

```
    [2013-10-11 21:25:58] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Attempt to assign property of non-object' in /path/to/laravel/app/controllers/HomeController.php:22
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/laravel/app/controllers/HomeController.php(22): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'Attempt to assi...', '/path/to/laravel...', 22, Array)
#1 [internal function]: HomeController->Index()
#2 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(5574): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(5562): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(HomeController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'Index')
#4 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(4901): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'HomeController', 'Index')
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#6 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(5155): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#7 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(4925): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(4914): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(548): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(532): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /path/to/laravel/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#12 {main} [] []
```

where the code is:

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
    | based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
    | get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
    |
    |   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
    |
    */

    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function Index()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('home'); //This is line 22
    }

}
```

My `BaseController`:

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller {

        /**
         * Setup the layout used by the controller.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        protected function setupLayout()
        {
                if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
                {
                        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
                }
        }

}
```

My `routes.php`

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@Index');
```

**Old problem:**

I have been working on Laravel 4.0.x on WAMP, and was going to deploy my site to my LEMP stack. However, I have been encountering this error:

```
[2013-10-09 01:20:00] log.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class filter.parser does not exist' in /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php:165
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(165): ReflectionClass->__construct('filter.parser')
#1 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(142): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('filter.parser', Array)
#2 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(442): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('filter.parser', Array)
#3 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(233): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('filter.parser')
#4 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controllers/Controller.php(104): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('filter.parser')
#5 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(4755): Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller->callAction(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router), 'Index', Array)
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#7 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(7824): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(7811): Illuminate\Routing\Route->callCallable()
#9 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(4766): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(481): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php(470): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /path/to/laravel/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#13 {main} [] []
```

When I remove my route which is basically

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@Index');
```

the error message changes to a Not Found instead. Not sure if this means anything, but I figured the error message was related to the routing.

The only differences I could think of were the composer packages (I even tried copying the `vendor` folder directly) or the PHP version (`5.4.12` on WAMP, `5.4.19` on LEMP).

I tried googling for the class name but I only found results to a closed github issue. Can anyone help me find out what's wrong?

For reference, the version of Laravel I am using is the same master branch on github - https://github.com/laravel/laravel

**My updated error after deleting `/path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php`**

```
 [2013-10-11 20:12:38] log.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class filter.parser does not exist' in /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:296
 Stack trace:
 #0 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(296): ReflectionClass->__construct('filter.parser')
 #1 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(238): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('filter.parser', Array)
 #2 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(425): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('filter.parser', Array)
 #3 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(468): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('filter.parser')
 #4 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controllers/Controller.php(104): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('filter.parser')
 #5 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(985): Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller->callAction(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router), 'Index', Array)
 #6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
 #7 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(80): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
 #8 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(47): Illuminate\Routing\Route->callCallable()
 #9 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1016): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
 #10 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(522): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
 #11 /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(497): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
 #12 /path/to/laravel/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
 #13 {main} [] []
```

**Apparent notable changes I made to my Laravel installation:**

At the end of `app/start/global.php`

```
-require app_path().'/filters.php';
+require app_path().'/filters.php';
+
+ClassLoader::register(new ClassLoader(array(
+    app_path().'/libraries',
+)));
+
+App::bind('html', function() {
+    return new HTML;
+});
```

Comment: Delete your file /path/to/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php, try again and replace the current error message with the new one, please.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro Done, is the purpose of that file just to act as a cache?

Comment: @xiankai Yeah it is just used as a cache

Comment: Can you just try an update ? ``composer update``

Comment: @devo I just tried that, and the weirdest error occurred - `[2013-10-11 21:12:25] log.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'PDO' not found' in /path/to/laravel/app/config/database.php:16` where line 16 is `'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,`

Comment: Then you have try a fresh installation and make sure you have pdo extension loaded.

Comment: Have you looked at your BaseController as I pointed in my edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Delete `vendor` directory and `composer.lock`.
- Run a `composer install --prefer-source`.
- Then go to: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/config/app.php and copy that into your `config/app.php`.
- Then run the following command: `php artisan key:generate`.
- Then just to be safe, run: `composer dump-autoload`.

**Your new problem:**

It looks like there is a problem regarding your base controller. Make sure your base controller looks like this:

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have replaced the config in `app/config/app.php` with that, but the resulting diff actually shows that a line was removed - `'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider'`, and that the ones from your list were already all there.

Comment: No luck, this is a relatively fresh Laravel install that only has the bare minimum config. `composer dump-autoload` gave a message `Generating autoload files` but changed nothing.

Comment: And try the same as above again but delete contents vendor directory first, then delete composer.lock, then run `composer install --prefer-source` instead of the first step.

Comment: Apparently upon reinstalling my `composer.json`, it seems I kind of had the `4.1` version of Laravel. I now have a new unrelated error... heh. But I did find a change to my installation I made last time that could have been part of a misguided pull from the official repo. I have updated my question to reflect that now. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: What route are you using to call your controller?

Comment: Updated my `routes.php` and `BaseController.php`

Comment: This might sound stupid but change your controller file name, class name and the link in your route to `HomeNewController`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39071/discussion-between-xiankai-and-adam-rivers)

Answer (score 2):

Did you moved from 4.1 back to 4.0?

You might need to check your app/config/app.php for this service provider:

```
'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
```

It might not be there, As Adam Rivers said.

Also check your aliases:

**for 4.0**

```
'Controller'      => 'Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller',
```

**for 4.1**

```
'Controller'      => 'Illuminate\Routing\Controller',
```

**EDIT:**

About your new problem, check if your BaseController, at least, looks like this:

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I did roll back to `4.0` (due to it removing support for controller routing), and the entry in my alias is the one for `4.0`. On the off-chance it was supposed to be `4.1`, I tried changing it but got `'ErrorException' with message 'Class 'Illuminate\Routing\Controller' not found' in /path/to/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php:64` instead.

Comment: Edited to guess about your new problem. Looks like `setupLayout()` is not being called.

Comment: Unfortunately `BaseController` looks exactly the same as what you pasted - I have not modified it. I have added the full stack trace, though. Debugging Laravel is such a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Delete bootstrap/**compiled.php** file. That should probably help.